# How can I return the data I get from an external API from the backend?

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, backend

I am consuming an external API with NodeJs. I'm confused, because I thought APIs could only be consumed from the frontend. The only way to return the data I get is through another API created by me, but I don't know if it's the best way to do this. Is there another way?

This is what I did to get the 'id' required by the url.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

app.get('/example/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    const url = `https://theexternalapiurl/${id}`;
    const config = { token }

    axios.get(url, config).then(response => {

        //here I should query a database and return a response
        console.log(response.data);
        res.json(data);
    });

});
```

Is it a good solution to create a second API to return the data?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean in here `The only way to return the data I get is through another API created by me`. Why do you need another API to return the data? What kind of data we are talking about here?

Comment: A lot of third-party APIs do not have CORS enabled, which means that you cannot call them from your own client application. Instead you need to build your own server application that queries that API on your behalf, sometimes called a proxy server since it acts as the go-between for your client and the third-party API. You can of course add additional logic to the requests if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is how it is usually done! It is a good practice to not expose third-party APIs directly to the client. You'll face unnecessary charges when duplicate or unnecessary calls are made.